# Not able to connect to SQL Server database due to SSL encryption not being implemented

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to setup a connection between Unity and a SQL Server database, but I am currently unable to do so due to SSL encryption.

Here's the error:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using to try to make the connection

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DB.Services
{
    public class DBServices
    {
        private const string _connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Players;Integrated Security=True;Trusted Connection=True";
        private SqlConnection _db;

        public string ConnectToDB()
        {
            _db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            _db.Open();

            if (_db.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                return "Connection failed";

            var users = GetUsers();
            return users;
        }

        private string GetUsers()
        {
            var query = "SELECT * FROM Player";

            SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(query, _db);
            var result = cmd.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _db.Close();

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Every other question I've seen has suggested that the connection string have 'Trusted Connection=True'. However, I continue to get the SSL encryption error.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to fix it?